# How can i combine a result from $elemMatch and push in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a problem.

This is my code:

How i structure the chats field in my mongoose schema:

```
chats: [
    {
        id: Number
        messages: [{text: String}]
    }
]
```

The code with the problem:

```
const u = await users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {
    chats: {$elemMatch: {id: req.params.id}}
})
```

I want to find a chat with the id i get from params, and then i want to push into the cat i found a new message into the messages field. i am not sure how i can do this.

Someone can help me pls?

Thank You ❤.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why I got -2? I'm not angry, I just do not understand why, I would be happy if the person who did it would state the reason, that way I can improve my questions.
Again, I'm not angry, just wondering why I got -2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) for this.
For example, `{text: 'newMessages'}` into chat id: 23452

```
db.collection.update(
{},
{$push: {"chats.$[c].messages": {text: 'newMessages'}}},
{arrayFilters: [{"c.id": 23452}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OTNJY6d6Dg5)